# How to use InternetSetOption to ignore self signed certificates

Tags: c, winapi, wininet, internetsetoption

I can't seem to figure out how to use `InternetSetOption()`

In [Setting and Retrieving Internet Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wininet/setting-and-retrieving-internet-options), the example is using `new INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION[3];` to allocate space for the `INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION` structs, but as far as I know C does not have a `new` keyword, so I tried to do it like below. Although this does not cause any errors, it does not fix the problem of making a request to a self-signed website.

```c
int request(char * host, int port,char * endpoint, char * data, size_t dlen )
{
    LPCSTR accept[] = {"*/*", NULL};
    char  hdrs[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
    HINTERNET hConnect, hSession, hRequest;
    hSession = InternetOpen("",
                            INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG,
                            NULL,
                            NULL,
                            0);
    INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST list;
    INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION ops[1];
    DWORD   dwBufSize = sizeof(list);
    list.dwSize = sizeof(list);
    list.pszConnection = NULL;
    list.dwOptionCount = 1;
    list.pOptions = ops;
    list.pOptions[0].dwOption = INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS;
    list.pOptions[0].Value.dwValue = SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA ;
    hConnect = InternetConnect(hSession,
                                host,
                                port,
                                NULL,
                                NULL,
                                INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP,0,1);
    hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hConnect,
                                "GET", 
                                endpoint,
                                _T("HTTP/1.1"),
                                NULL,
                                accept,
                                INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID|INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE,1);
    if (!InternetSetOption(hRequest, INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS, &list, dwBufSize))
        printf("Failed to set options Error: %ld\n", GetLastError());
    if (hRequest == NULL)
        printf("Error: %ld\n", GetLastError());
    if (HttpSendRequest(hRequest, hdrs, strlen(hdrs), data, dlen))
    {
        DWORD received;
        char tmp[MAX_LEN];
        while (InternetReadFile(hRequest, tmp, MAX_LEN, &received) && received)   
            printf("%s\n", tmp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How does one use `InternetSetOption()` to set the `SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA`?

Comment: Set it on the connection handle?

Comment: MSDN does not list SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA as a valid flag here?

Comment: SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA is used with WinHttpSetOption(), not InternetSetOption()

Comment: @RemyLebeau what is the equivalent of `SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA ` to `InternetSetOption()`

Comment: @loaded_dypper nevermind, I stand corrected. `SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA` also works with `InternetSetOption()`, via the `INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS` option

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes but this does not fix the problem of ignoring self-signed certificates

Comment: `INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAG` is not one of the [documented options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/ns-wininet-internet_per_conn_optionw) supported by `INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION`. Have you tried using `INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAG` by itself? `InternetSetOption(..., INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAG, ...)` Also, when using `INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION`, you are passing in `hSession` when you should be passing in `hConnect` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau please check the full function that I am using, as for `INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAG` this does not work and throws undefined error and only using `internetSetOption` with `hRequest` results in no errors but still not connection on the server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `InternetSetOption` in the wrong way, A quick internet search will yeild lots of examples but here is how to use it in your case

```c
int request(char * host, int port,char * endpoint, char * data, size_t dlen )
{
    LPCSTR accept[] = {"*/*", NULL};
    char  hdrs[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
    HINTERNET hConnect, hSession, hRequest;
    DWORD dwFlags;
    DWORD dwBuffLen = sizeof(dwFlags);
    hSession = InternetOpen("",
                            INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT,
                            NULL,
                            NULL,
                            0);

    hConnect = InternetConnect(hSession,
                                host,
                                port,
                                NULL,
                                NULL,
                                INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP,0,1);
    hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hConnect,
                                "GET", 
                                endpoint,
                                _T("HTTP/1.1"),
                                NULL,
                                accept,
                                INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID|INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE,1);
    if (!InternetSetOption(hRequest, INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS, &dwFlags, dwBuffLen))
        printf("Failed to set options Error: %ld\n", GetLastError());
    if (hRequest == NULL)
        printf("Error: %ld\n", GetLastError());
    if (InternetQueryOption (hRequest, INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS, &dwFlags, &dwBuffLen))
    {
        dwFlags |= SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA|SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID|SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_DATE_INVALID;
        InternetSetOption (hRequest, INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS, &dwFlags, sizeof (dwFlags));
    }
    if (HttpSendRequest(hRequest, hdrs, strlen(hdrs), data, dlen))
    {
        DWORD received;
        char tmp[MAX_LEN];
        while (InternetReadFile(hRequest, tmp, MAX_LEN, &received) && received)   
            printf("%s\n", tmp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It is also worth paying attention to the parameters of `InternetSetOption` from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetsetoptiona)